# Google Distance Matrix not getting distance

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, google-distancematrix-api

I have roughly tried to parse the JSON from [Google Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/), but it is not showing the distance.

My GPS location is not `0,0` that I'm sure of.

> String distance = getMatrix(latitude,longitude);

My code for the function is:

```
private String getMatrix(double lat , double lang){
  JSONObject jObj;
  String getdistance = "";
  String strUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" 
                  + Double.toString(my_lat) + "," 
                  + Double.toString(my_lang) 
                  + "&destinations="+ Double.toString(lat) + "," 
                  + Double.toString(lang) 
                  + "&mode=walking&sensor=false";

  String data = "";
  InputStream reader = null;
  HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
  try{
    URL url = new URL(strUrl);
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.connect();

    reader = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    int bRead = -1;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    do {
      bRead = reader.read(buffer, 0, 1024);
      if (bRead == -1) {
        break;
      }
      data += new String(buffer, 0, bRead);
    } while (true);
    urlConnection.disconnect();
  } catch(Exception e) {
  } finally {

  }

  try {
    jObj = new JSONObject(data);

    JSONArray rowsArray = jObj.getJSONArray("rows");
    JSONObject rows = rowsArray.getJSONObject(0);

    JSONArray elementsArray = rows.getJSONArray("elements");
    JSONObject newDisTimeOb = elementsArray.getJSONObject(0);

    JSONObject distOb = newDisTimeOb.getJSONObject("distance");
    getdistance = distOb.optString("text").toString();
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return getdistance;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check if you've correctly build the url string in the code:

```
String strUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" 
                  + Double.toString(my_lat) + "," 
                  + Double.toString(my_lang) 
                  + "&destinations="+ Double.toString(lat) + "," 
                  + Double.toString(lang) 
                  + "&mode=walking&sensor=false";

// Line to check if url code is right
Log.d("APP", "strUrl = " + strUrl);
```

Then check your following code, whether it really produce the data:

```
reader = urlConnection.getInputStream();
int bRead = -1;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
do {
  bRead = reader.read(buffer, 0, 1024);
  if (bRead == -1) {
    break;
  }
  data += new String(buffer, 0, bRead);
} while (true);
```

My suggestion is to use `BufferedReader` instead reading the response byte per byte.

Then change:

```
getdistance = distOb.optString("text").toString();
```

to

```
getdistance = distOb.getString("text");
```

Because you don't need to convert to string again here.

I've search [Client Libraries for Google Maps Web Services](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/client-library) and found  [DistanceMatrixApi.java](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java/blob/cc78172abd28b99cda71e5e3dd3d95bca0bebfd4/src/main/java/com/google/maps/DistanceMatrixApi.java). Maybe we can use it, but I can't assure of it.

Comment: Can you take a look at this question ?   https://stackoverflow.com/q/56397604/4425004

Comment: I'm marking you as the right answer because of &mode=walking&sensor=false this line in kotlin you do like this  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=48.856052,2.3537521&destinations=22.2600054,70.7869376&key=AIzaSyDYvqEW16HdPdIRXCncIIGtjQ-4bbQk0i0&mode=walking&sensor=false