# How to display google distance matrix API response in grid cell per row?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, google-distancematrix-api

I want to display a grid with start and destination travel point with google distance matrix response value of the same. For this, I have GPS coordinates of origin and destination in the array. I am able to build the grid, and I am unable to fill the google distance in each row from the API callbacks.

`var dataArray = [];`

//Using Ajax request to get the result from DB.

```
success:function(data.d)
dataArray = data.d.slice();
```

//sample data set are : StartLatitude, StartLongitude, EndLatitude, EndLongitude, UserName, LoggedTime,etc..

Here i need to show the array as grid in web application, with a column representing the google distance for each distance traveled by the user

//Deferred execution is used here

```
GoogleDistance().then(LoadGrid);
```

//Get the distance of each record using google distance matrix API

```
var responseCount = [];
var GoogleDistance = function () {
     var defer = $.Deferred();
     var distanceService = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
     responseCount = [];
     //dataArray => has the grid row details , which includes gps origin and destination info

    for (i = 0; i <= (dataArray.length - 1) ; i++) {
            distanceService.getDistanceMatrix(
            {
                origins: [{ lat: parseFloat(dataArray[i].StartLatitude), lng: parseFloat(dataArray[i].StartLongitude) }],
                destinations: [{ lat: parseFloat(dataArray[i].EndLatitude), lng: parseFloat(dataArray[i].EndLongitude) }],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
                avoidHighways: false,
                avoidTolls: false
            }, function (response, status) {
                if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
                    //validation
                } else {
                    if (origin == "") responseCount.push(0);
                    else if (destination == "") responseCount.push(0);
                    else if (response.rows[0].elements[0].status === "ZERO_RESULTS") responseCount.push(0);
                    else if (response.rows[0].elements[0].status === "NOT_FOUND") responseCount.push(0);
                    else {
                        var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance;
                        var distance_text = distance.text;
                        responseCount.push(distance_text);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
        //to overcome asynchrounous execution and gather all API response 
        var tid = setInterval(ValidateGoogleResponseCount, 200);
        function ValidateGoogleResponseCount() {
            if (responseCount.length == dataArray.length) {
                //console.log("response ready");
                abortTimer();
                defer.resolve(); // When this fires, the code in a().then(/..../); is executed.
                return defer;
            }
        }
        function abortTimer() { // to be called when you want to stop the timer
            clearInterval(tid);
        }
        return defer;
    }
```

//Build Grid with Google distance response

```
var LoadGrid = function () {
var defer = $.Deferred();
var tableInfo = "";
$.each(selectedInfo, function (index, travelInfo) {
     tableInfo += '<tr class="tdInfo">' +
        '<td>' + travelInfo.StartPoint + '</td>'+
        '<td>' + travelInfo.EndPoint + '</td>'
        '<td class="text-center ActualDistance">' + responseCount[index] + 
'</td>' +
});
 defer.resolve();
 return defer;
};
```

I am able to get the response for all request and which is stored in an array `responseCount`. Order of coordinates used for API request is always same, but the order of response is different for different execution. So I am unable to bind the correct matching result in the grid cell.

Critical Issues are: JQuery Asynchronous execution, Google API Response order,